Cant Install SASS on Windows 7
I am studying web development and outside of WebDev I don't have technical computer skills.
I still have  Windows 7 and I installed the last Node.JS that is compatible and then I follow instructions and install SASS in VSCODE Terminal and I get a lot of messages during the installation about compatibility(not sure what exactly its saying), but it did seem to install.
*screen clip attached.(https://i.sstatic.net/h75L2.png)
I see it also says powershell failed to activate.
Its probably useless already but I ran a simple tutorial on how to check if SASS is working, by creating a simple  style.css file with some code and then tried to convert it to style.css with this code in the Terminal sass style.scss style.css and I get an error.
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
At line:1 char:5

sass <<<<  style.scss style.css

CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException



I am sorry, I am so new with this Powershell and Node.JS the whole command line is like foreign language to me.
Can I get SASS working on my system or is my system outdated and there is no way to get SASS working?
I tried to install SASS and failed.

It's a Powershell issue. Your system doesn't allow running of ps1 files. You would have to do this, and then try sass style.scss style.css again.
